Given $\int_0^{2x}f(t) dt = 4x \sin(x)$, find $f'(2\pi)$
Problem: Given $\int_0^{2x}f(t) dt = 4x \sin(x)$, find $f'(2\pi)$.
I tried doing it with $2$ different approaches, however, they gave me different answers.
Approach 1
$$
\begin{align}
2f(2x) &= 4(\sin x + x\cos x)\\
\implies
f(2x) &= 2(\sin x + x\cos x)\\
\implies f(x) &= 2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) + x\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\\
\implies f '(x) &= 2\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) - \frac{x}{2}\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\\
\implies f '(2π) &= -2
\end{align}
$$
Approach 2
$$
\begin{align}
2f(2x) &= 4(\sin x + x\cos x)\\
\implies
f(2x) &= 2(\sin x + x\cos x)\\
\implies
f '(2x) &= 4\cos x - 2x\sin x\\
\implies f'(2\pi) &= -4\\
\end{align}
$$
Which approach is correct?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

@AnneBauval Done.

The first approach is fine. Concerning the second one, note that$$f(2x)=2(\sin(x)+x\cos(x))\implies\color{red}2f'(2x)=4\cos(x)-2x\sin(x).$$

@geetha290krm Such as… ?

I am extremely sorry. I did not read the first approach correctly. Sincere apologies.  I have now upvoted your answer.

@AnneBauval I was an idiot. Made comments without reading OP's approach correctly. Your contribution in setting things right is much appreciated.
